# How to make the While-Loop start from the beginning on in Python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm currently learning Python and now im stuck on a problem. I want that the program starts again at the beginning where you can choose what units to convert after converting a temperature.

For example you press 1 to convert Celsius into Kelvin. You type in a temperature in Celsius and it then gives you the answer in Kelvin. But now it is stuck in (1) and i only can convert other temperatures from Celsius to Kelvin.

I tried using continue and brake at some points but im pretty sure this is wrong. As i said im a beginner.

```py
import sys

print("(0) Exit")
print("(1) Umrechnung von Celsius nach Kelvin\n(2) Umrechnung von Celsius nach Fahrenheit")
print("(3) Umrechnung von Kelvin nach Celsius\n(4) Umrechnung von Kelvin nach Fahrenheit")
print("(5) Umrechnung von Fahrenheit nach Celsius\n(6) Umrechnung von Fahrenheit nach Kelvin")
ntask = int(input("Eingabe: "))

while True:
    if ntask == 1:
        d_input = input("Celsius: ")
        d_output = (float(d_input) + 273.15)
        if d_output < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei -273.15°C.")
        else:
            print("Kelvin: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 2:
        d_input = input("Celsius: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input)*9/5)+32)
        print("Fahrenheit: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 3:
        d_input = input("Kelvin: ")
        if int(d_input) < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei 0K.")
        else:
            d_output = (float(d_input) - 273.15)
            print("Celsius: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 4:
        d_input = input("Kelvin: ")
        if int(d_input) < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei 0K.")
        else:
            d_output = ((float(d_input) - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32)
            print("Fahrenheit: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 5:
        d_input = input("Fahrenheit: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input) - 32) * 5/9)
        print("Celsius: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 6:
        d_input = input("Fahrenheit: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15)
        if d_output < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei circa -459,67°F.")
        else:
            print("Kelvin: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 0:
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        print("Ungültige Eingabe")
```

Comment: Why don't you simply move the first `input` into the `while` loop as well?

Comment: @Selcuk Urgh, that makes so much sense. How didn't I come up with this idea... Thank you so much!

Comment: @Selcuk Why mark it as a duplicate? I asked how to solve this problem by using a while-loop. The other question creates a function for it where i need to make an input (Y/N).

Comment: I didn't flag it as a duplicate (that yellow box is confusing) and I agree that that is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Prune Consider taking another look to the duplicate question?

Comment: @Selcuk Good to know, again thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does

```
import sys

while True:
    print("(0) Exit")
    print("(1) Umrechnung von Celsius nach Kelvin\n(2) Umrechnung von Celsius nach Fahrenheit")
    print("(3) Umrechnung von Kelvin nach Celsius\n(4) Umrechnung von Kelvin nach Fahrenheit")
    print("(5) Umrechnung von Fahrenheit nach Celsius\n(6) Umrechnung von Fahrenheit nach Kelvin")
    ntask = int(input("Eingabe: "))
    if ntask == 1:
        d_input = input("Celsius: ")
        d_output = (float(d_input) + 273.15)
        if d_output < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei -273.15°C.")
        else:
            print("Kelvin: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 2:
        d_input = input("Celsius: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input)*9/5)+32)
        print("Fahrenheit: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 3:
        d_input = input("Kelvin: ")
        if int(d_input) < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei 0K.")
        else:
            d_output = (float(d_input) - 273.15)
            print("Celsius: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 4:
        d_input = input("Kelvin: ")
        if int(d_input) < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei 0K.")
        else:
            d_output = ((float(d_input) - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32)
            print("Fahrenheit: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 5:
        d_input = input("Fahrenheit: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input) - 32) * 5/9)
        print("Celsius: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 6:
        d_input = input("Fahrenheit: ")
        d_output = ((float(d_input) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15)
        if d_output < 0:
            print("Der absolute Nullpunkt liegt bei circa -459,67°F.")
        else:
            print("Kelvin: ", d_output)

    elif ntask == 0:
        sys.exit(0)

    else:
        print("Ungültige Eingabe")
```

Work as you intend?